# are string immutable in kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin

I'm trying to learn Kotlin by reading its documentation. in the documentation there is a section about string. in that section it says:

> Strings are immutable. Once you initialize a string, you can't change
> its value or assign a new value to it. All operations that transform
> strings return their results in a new String object, leaving the
> original string unchanged.

and tries to show that with an example:

```
fun main() {
    val str = "abcd"
    println(str.uppercase()) // Create and print a new String object
    println(str) // the original string remains the same
}
```

I have a problem with the part that says:

> the value of strings can't change after initializing.

but when I change the `val` to `var` I easily can change the value of the string.

so what the documentation means by saying the value of string can't be changed? we know that `val` makes variables immutable, not just for strings.

Comment: Even with `var`, `str.uppercase()` will not change the value. You must have assigned a *new* string to the `str` variable.

Comment: As @AdamMillerchip said `String.uppercase()` is not a [`inplace`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) function and hence no change , and `val` is Read-only.

Comment: I know that functions would not change the value of the original string. it has clearly been said in the doc. The document's first line seems to be talking about string class per se. not the functions.@AdamMillerchip

Comment: as I said, I'm not talking about the functions. my problem is with `Strings are immutable. Once you initialize a string, you can't change its value or assign a new value to it` @Anshul

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the JVM semantics around this are, so I don't feel qualified to post an answer. But my understanding of this paragraph is that you can change *what data the binding points to*, but you cannot actually change the pointed-to data. So you can create a new string and point `str` to that new string, but you cannot modify the existing string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> but when I change the `val` to `var` I easily can change the value of the string.

No, you cannot easily do that. Suppose you had:

```
var str = "foo"
```

This is not changing the value of the string `"foo"`:

```
str = "bar"
```

You are just taking another instance of `String` and putting it inside the property `str`.

Notice that there is a difference between "the string" and "the property". "The string" refers to the instance of the `String` class that you created by doing `"foo"`. That instance is immutable. You cannot do anything to it to make that same instance have a different sequence of characters than f, o, o. This is because the `String` class provides no public members that do this, and this is what the documentation was referring to when it says "`String` is immutable".

On the other hand, "the property" is the `str` that you declared by saying `var str = ...`, and it *is* mutable. It stores instances of `String`s, and you can change what instances it stores. **But you can't change the strings themselves**, once they are created.

Compare this with lists. `List` is immutable, yet you can still do:

```
var myList: List<Int> = listOf(1, 2, 3)
```

Now suppose you want to remove all 3s in the list. You must create a new list:

```
// "filter" creates a new list
myList = myList.filter { it != 3 }
```

because `List` is immutable, and it does not have any methods that does this without creating a new list. If `myList` were a `MutableList`, however, you could have done:

```
// this does not create a new list
myList.removeIf { it == 3 }
```

There is no `MutableString` though :)

Comment: `CharArray` is basically `MutableString`.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you’re confused by two different things:

- reference management in Kotlin (var vs val)
- String immutability

So to start with immutability:
When you create an object it occupies some place in memory and contains “abcd” in your example.

The immutability means that you can’t change anything in this memory area, for example it’s impossible to make those bytes in memory to hold a string “abcE”. In general immutability means that you cannot change an internal state of the object after it has been created. This is a Design decisions of people who have developed a String class.
They could easily provide API for changing the state (setters for example) but they chose to avoid doing so for many reasons which are beyond the scope of this question.

Now as for reference management:
Usually you don’t just create a String (which is still immutable) but also maintain a reference to it so that you could address it from your program.
There are two types of reference which confuse you.
If you define a reference with a `val` keyword - this means that you won’t be able to “point” this reference to any other object, on the other hand, if you work with `var` keyword,  its possible to assign another object to that reference:

```
val s = “abc”
s=“def” // impossible

var k = “abc”
k = “def” // ok
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the reference to the `String` with the instance of the `String`.

For a value to change, it's inner state must change. For a string object, once it is instantiated, it is never changed. However any references on that `String` may be reassigned another `String` instance, if they are themselves mutable.

```kotlin
val s = "My String"
var t = s
t = t + " Stuff"
println(s) // yields "My String"
```

Not only can no operator change the inner state of the `String`, but also no method on the `String`.

E.g. there exist languages, where you can do the following:

```
// note, this is pseudocode, and *not* kotlin semantics
final String someString = "Some String";
someString.cutFromEnd(" String");
println(someString); // could yield "Some" in some language.
```

Answer (score 1):

To explain in one sentence , `String value remains immutable but the string variable is mutable` .

Consider two string val a = "123" and val 2= "123" , then instead of creating two instances in the string pool , it creates only one instance and returns that instance to both the variables . String pool is an storage area in the heap memory. So hence ,when a string is created and if the string already exists in the pool, the reference of the existing string will be returned, instead of creating a new object and returning its reference. If string is not immutable, changing the string with one reference will lead to the wrong value for the other references. So when you change the value of one variable , it searches in the heap whether the value exist , if not  it creates a new value in the heap else derives it from already existing one .